# Get number of <select> items inside change() function

Tags: jquery

I have the following js code:

```
$("#mySelector").change(function(){
  console.log($(this).length);
});
```

I know this is wrong code to get the number of items in selector. But how should I get this number in correct way?

P.S.
In normal way I should use `$("#mySelector option").length` to get this number. But how to add `option` to `$(this)` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#mySelector").on('change', function(){
  console.log($('select', this).length);
});
```

or for options ?

```
$("#mySelector").on('change', function(){
  console.log($('option', this).length);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fCQKx/)

Answer (score 0):

if your attempting to get the total `<option>` tags in a select drop down you can do this

```
options = 0;
$('{selector} option').each(function() {
    options++;
});
alert(options);​
```

or a much better way as suggested by the fine vega

```
$('{selector} option').length
```

Comment: or simply `$('{selector} option').length`

Comment: touche that is a much better alternative